# Expected value sum of dots

Tags: probability

We throw $n$-times the die. Let $E_n$ be expected value sum of dots (got in all throws).
Compute

1. $E_1$
2. $E_2$
3. $E_3$
4. $E_4$

So i know how can I do it, for example in 1. I have:

1. $E_1 = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 2 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 3 \cdot \frac{1}{6}  + 4 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 5 \cdot \frac{1}{6} + 6 \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{2}$.

Similar:

$E_2 =  2 \cdot \frac{1}{36} + 3 \cdot \frac{2}{36} + 4 \cdot \frac{3}{36} + 5 \cdot \frac{4}{36}+ 6 \cdot \frac{5}{36} + 7 \cdot \frac{6}{36} + 8 \cdot \frac{5}{36} + 9 \cdot \frac{4}{36} + 10 \cdot \frac{3}{36} + 11 \cdot \frac{2}{36} + 12 \cdot \frac{1}{36} = 7$

It is easy but for $E_3$ and $E_4$ it will be compute very long. I suppose that exist easier way to do this task. I will grateful for your help.

Comment: $E_n=$ $___$ $\times E_1$.

Comment: Yes, there is a much easier way. Expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations.

Comment: I suppose that $E_n = n \times E_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $X=X_{1}+,...,+X_{n}$ where $X_{i}, i \in \{1,...,n\}$ is the number of dots on the throw $i$ then you need $E[X]$. So, because expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations

$$E[X]=E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\right]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}E{\left[X_i\right]}$$

but $E[X_i]=E[X_j]$ for all $i,j$ because $X_i$ and $X_j$ are identically distributed and

$$E[X_i]=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{6}j\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{6}\frac{42}{2}=\frac{7}{2}$$

then

$$E[X]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{7}{2}=\frac{7}{2}n.$$

Comment: As I understood, $$X_1 = \left\{1,...,6 \right\} \\ X_2 = \left\{2,...,12 \right\} \\ X_3 = \left\{3,...,18 \right\} $$ and so on. So I don't understand yet why $X=X_1 + ... + X_n$ ?

Comment: No, $X_i\in \{1,...,6\}$ because are the possible outcomes in the throw $i$. Then sum up all $X_i$ you will get $X$ (the number of total dots in $n$ throws).

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_n$ denote the number of dots thrown on the $n$th try. Then $$E_n = E[\sum_1^n X_i] = \sum_1^nE[X_i] = n E_1$$
do you see how to finish?